# Joining two scripts

Tags: regex, powershell, directory, watch

First I made new script that make regex :

```
$input_path = 'C:\site-download\input.txt'
$output_file = 'C:\site-download\output.txt'
$regex = '(?<month>VPIP<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'
$regex2 = '(?<month>Winrate<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{1}.\d{1})'
$regex3 = '(?<month>PFR<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'
$regex4 = '(?<month>Winnings<\/span><span class=""right"">\-[0-9]{1,9})'
$regex5 = '(?<month>3Bet<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{1}.\d{1})'

Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex2 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex3 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex4 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex5 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
```

Its working good so far.

Second script I found in web (also working good):

```
Function Register-Watcher {
    param ($folder)
    $filter = "*.*" #all files
    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }

    $changeAction = [scriptblock]::Create('
        # This is the code which will be executed every time a file change is detected
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    ')

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action $changeAction
}

Register-Watcher "C:\site-download"
```

So basically I'm working to find out how I can add first script to second.
I tried something this:

```
Function Register-Watcher {
    param ($folder)
    $filter = "*.*" #all files
    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }

    $changeAction = [scriptblock]::Create('
        # This is the code which will be executed every time a file change is detected
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"

        $input_path = $name
        $output_file = 'C:\site-download\output.txt'
        $regex = '(?<month>VPIP<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'
        $regex2 = '(?<month>Winrate<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{1}.\d{1})'
        $regex3 = '(?<month>PFR<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})'
        $regex4 = '(?<month>Winnings<\/span><span class=""right"">\-[0-9]{1,9})'
        $regex5 = '(?<month>3Bet<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{1}.\d{1})'

        Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
        Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex2 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
        Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex3 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
        Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex4 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
        Select-String -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex5 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
    ')

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action $changeAction
}

Register-Watcher "C:\site-download"
```

But keep getting some errors:

```
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:21
+ select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_ ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Sel‌​ectStringCommand
```

Can someone help me out to fix this last script?

Comment: "some errors." - which errors? and where?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of error messages, and particularly not on some external site that may disappear at any given time. Copy and paste the error message text into your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. 
Error code:
Select-String : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:21
+ select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_ ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStrin
   gCommand

Answer (score 0):

Your regex script has single quotes (') in it which are breaking your scriptblock. Replace them with double quotes (").

Comment: Also are you editing your PowerShell with an ISE like PowerShell ISE? I pasted your code into an ISE and the error showed up instantly.

Comment: I am trying  power-shell ISE.

Comment: Removed  single quotes ('), but still cant get it working as i wish.

Answer (score 0):

What i have tested now:

```
Function Register-Watcher {
    param ($folder)
    $filter = "*.*" #all files
    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }

    $changeAction = [scriptblock]::Create('
        # This is the code which will be executed every time a file change is detected
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Write-Host "The file $name was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    ')

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Created" -Action $changeAction
}


 Register-Watcher "C:\site-download"

 Function regex-inout { $input_path = 'C:\site-download\input.txt'
$output_file = "C:\site-download\output.txt"
$regex = "(?<month>VPIP<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})"
$regex2 = "(?<month>Winrate<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{1}.\d{1})"
$regex3 = "(?<month>PFR<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{2}.\d{1})"
$regex4 = "(?<month>Winnings<\/span><span class=""right"">\-[0-9]{1,9})"
$regex5 = "(?<month>3Bet<\/span><span class=""right"">\d{1}.\d{1})"

select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex2 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex3 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex4 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } |Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex5 -List | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.Value } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '</span><span class=""right"">', ' = '} | Add-Content $output_file

} regex-inout
```

Folder watch working good. But where should i move Function regex-inout so that when new files come to folder then this regex start work. At moment only folder watch working and regex didn't  do nothing.

Sorry for my bad English.